# Fill array with values from another array

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to fill an array with values from another array. This is what I have by now:

```
  public data: any[] = [{
  {
    text: 'Category', items: [
      { text: 'All Categories' },
      { text: 'Cat1' },
      { text: 'Cat2' },
      { text: 'Cat3' },
    ]
  }, {
    text: 'Customers', items:
      this.clients_name.map(text => ({ text }))
  }];
```

where `clients_name = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

I expect on console.log `data[1]` to be:

```
items: (4) […]
0: Object { text: "a" }    ​​
1: Object { text: "b" }
2: Object { text: "c" }
3: Object { text: "d" }
length: 4
<prototype>: Array []
text: "Customers"
```

but I get

```
items: []
length: 0
<prototype>: Array []
text: "Customers"
```

Why isn't filling the `data` array properly? Thank you for your time!

Comment: `this.clients_name` appears to be an empty array at the time `.map()` is called on it.

Comment: Oooh, you are right. I checked that. Thank you! You can give an answer so I can mark it.

Comment: @Tenzolinho  did you fixed the issue ?

Comment: Yes, I did solve it. The code was correct, just `clients_name` empty at the moment I tried to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this.clients_name is empty array try to initialize it before you perform this operation.